# Characteristics or Preferences of Age Groups When Learning/Acquiring a Language

Tags: learning-methods, linguistics, age

I've been looking for some research studies to get into more depth about the characteristics of age groups when learning a language. My main focus is on ages of 17 and 18 (basically, when teenagers turn into young adults).

For example, somewhere in the internet I have read that their institution prioritises collaborative teaching, or creating as much interaction as possible because students at this age (pedagogically) wants to interact with each other and adapts a social learning environment easily.

I've tried many search queries on Google Scholar but can't say I found something useful. I want to stay away from the CEFR because I want some real evidence.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated. You'd make me extra happy if you can provide article titles or links.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. I would appreciate it if you could make your question a bit more focused: (1) stating which specific age group you are interested in (instead of "preferences of age groups" and adding what your main focus is); (2) whether this is about how that age group likes to be taught (17-18-year old usually learn language at school, so you might ask about teaching methods instead of learning methods) and (3) add whether this is about specific countries or cultures, since teaching methods can differ between countries.